# Compiling Java class with nested subclass all of a sudden won't work, "access denied"

Tags: java, linux

I have a Java servlet on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian wheezy. When I try to compile this .java file from within Tomcat's /lib directory (as I always do) today, it suddenly fails. It points to the private class declaration and says access denied. What could have changed, that was previously working?

I try

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/lib $ javac -cp servlet-api.jar:gson-2.2.3.jar:gson-2.2.3-sources.jar ../webapps/sample/WEB-INF/classes/mypackage/Response.java
```

and get (translated to English from Swedish)

```
../webapps/sample/WEB-INF/classes/mypackage/Response.java:65: error: error while writing Response.Ticket: ../webapps/sample/WEB-INF/classes/mypackage/Response$Ticket.class (Ã
tkomst nekas)
    private class Ticket {
            ^
1 error
```

In the /mypackage directory, I have a compiled file for the nested class, Response$Ticket.class that I didn't notice before, but I guess it was always there?

edit: Problem solved.

Comment: Check the file system permissions where you're compiling your files. `Parentclass$NestedClass.class` is how javac generates the inner classes, so that's not the issue.

Comment: It looks like a permission issue. Did you check you have write access to ../webapps/sample/WEB-INF/classes/mypackage with current user?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any Java errors in there. For me, this looks like that you don't have the permissions to write the file `../webapps/sample/WEB-INF/classes/mypackage/Response$Ticket.class`

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry you guys. All it was, was me leaving out a simple "sudo". I'm still a bit unaccustomed to Linux it seems.

Thanks for the swift replies!